# Divs in a row are not centralising in desktop mode

Tags: html, css

The divs within my row are sitting centrally on mobile mode, but for the life of me they wont sit centrally now on desktop, i've tried absolutely everything, googled every method, I MUST somewhere in one of the container divs somehow disabled the ability to centralise them?

Mobile mode:

[image]

Desktop:

[image]

the code (i've tried including everything) - I must also apologise for the inline css, all css is inline except for this span element - shop__info-title .....

```css
.shop__info-title {
    color: #626262;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="box-sizing: border-box;"id="shopify-section-product-shop-specs" class="shopify-section">
  <section style="text-align: center; padding: 30px 0px; background-color: #f5f5f5;" id="shop__info">
    <div style="width: 100%;padding-right: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div style="position: relative;width: 100%;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;"class="col-md-10 col-12">
          <div style="display: flex; margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;" class="row">
            <div style="padding: 0px 12px; border-right: 1px solid black;"class="col-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s" data-wow-delay="0.5s" style="visibility:visible; animation-duration: 1.4s; animation-delay: 0.5s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0105/3432/2257/files/icon-truck_39af13e6-bdae-41e5-a6b6-a6fd39550f6d.png?v=1574974629" alt="Quick Shipping" class="shop__info-icon">
              <span class="shop__info-title">Quick Shipping</span>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 0px 12px; border-right: 1px solid black;"class="col-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s" data-wow-delay="0.6s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1.4s; animation-delay: 0.6s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0105/3432/2257/files/icon-returns_39cbb557-2863-40fb-b32d-bf0e57870c3a.png?v=1574974639" alt="Easy Returns" class="shop__info-icon">
              <span class="shop__info-title">Easy Returns</span>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 0px 12px;"class="col-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s" data-wow-delay="0.7s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1.4s; animation-delay: 0.7s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0105/3432/2257/files/icon-chat_e5a25495-03db-41d5-ad38-86ea5c5e8220.png?v=1574974651" alt="24/7 Support" class="shop__info-icon">
              <span class="shop__info-title">24/7 Support</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Thanks so much if you can help. having a nightmare.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `justify-content: center;` to `.row` to achieve this, since it flex display.

Snippet:

```js
.shop__info-title {
    color: #626262;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    display: block;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div style="box-sizing: border-box;"id="shopify-section-product-shop-specs" class="shopify-section">
  <section style="text-align: center; padding: 30px 0px; background-color: #f5f5f5;" id="shop__info">
    <div style="width: 100%;padding-right: 15px;margin-right: auto;margin-left: auto;"class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div style="position: relative;width: 100%;padding-right: 15px;padding-left: 15px;"class="col-md-10 col-12">
          <div style="display: flex; margin-right: -15px; margin-left: -15px;  justify-content: center;" class="row">
            <div style="padding: 0px 12px; border-right: 1px solid black;"class="col-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s" data-wow-delay="0.5s" style="visibility:visible; animation-duration: 1.4s; animation-delay: 0.5s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0105/3432/2257/files/icon-truck_39af13e6-bdae-41e5-a6b6-a6fd39550f6d.png?v=1574974629" alt="Quick Shipping" class="shop__info-icon">
              <span class="shop__info-title">Quick Shipping</span>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 0px 12px; border-right: 1px solid black;"class="col-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s" data-wow-delay="0.6s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1.4s; animation-delay: 0.6s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0105/3432/2257/files/icon-returns_39cbb557-2863-40fb-b32d-bf0e57870c3a.png?v=1574974639" alt="Easy Returns" class="shop__info-icon">
              <span class="shop__info-title">Easy Returns</span>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 0px 12px;"class="col-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1.4s" data-wow-delay="0.7s" style="visibility: visible; animation-duration: 1.4s; animation-delay: 0.7s; animation-name: fadeInUp;">
              <img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0105/3432/2257/files/icon-chat_e5a25495-03db-41d5-ad38-86ea5c5e8220.png?v=1574974651" alt="24/7 Support" class="shop__info-icon">
              <span class="shop__info-title">24/7 Support</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```